# Hiding Selected item with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have this code

```
  $("#tag_price").on('change', function(event) {
     if ($(this).val() == -2)
      $('<input type="text" class="ipt" id="customprice" name="customPrice" />').insertAfter(this),
      $('<p id="customprice" class="semi_margin_top">Introduce el precio exacto</p>').insertAfter(this);
     else if ($(this).val() !== -2)
      $('#customprice').hide;
  });
```

The first part is working, when the input has value -2, the second input is shown. But I want it to dissappear when another value is selected, because if not the second input will remain forever.

I want the second input ONLY to show when value -2 is selected, and dissappear when another value is selected. I thought I could achieve that with Jquery and hide, but I't wont work.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `hide()` instead of `hide`.

Comment: The second `if` comparison is redundant. You only need `} else {`.

Comment: Didn't realize I wansnt calling the method @IsmailBadawi. That made the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The corollary to `hide()` you're looking for is [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/). There are a few other issues with your code that you'll need to take care of as well.

First, you're missing { } around your `if` statement, so your `else if` should be throwing an error as the `$('<p...')` line is outside of the if.

Secondly, there's no need for `else if` as there isn't a 3rd option. The value is either "-2" or it isn't.

Right now, you're appending a new element every time that someone selects the "-2" item, which is not the right way to do it. Check to see if those elements are already in the DOM, and only add them if they aren't there. If they are, then call `show()`.

```
if ($(this).val() === -2) {
    $('#customprice').show();
}
```